# Console formatter for pas / Delphi sources

Tags: delphi, formatting

I want to automate formatting Delphi code before adding it to Git, but my favorite CnPack is able to format code only from IDE. Is there any standalone application that can format Delphi source code from command line?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's built-in code formatter can be run from the [command line](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Formatter.EXE,_the_Command_Line_Formatter).

Comment: Can you explain how to run it from the command line instead of just saying that it is possible to do it via command line?

Comment: @Martin: Formatter.exe is in RAD Studio's bin folder and the link in my answer explains the parameters. You can point to one of the bundled format configurations or to a custom one that you've created yourself.